# Python multiprocessing, stuck with a looping problem

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So I have this Idea of running discord bot script from a `mainloop`. Concurrently with this bot running, I would like to run a "main loop", that will always be ready to act on a signal.
The bot will is able to add elements to a list through an add-function. But the while-loop seem to not be getting this updated length value. It always assumes that the length of `datesList` is `0`.
My thinking is that the while loop should be printing 1's and 2's when an element is added to `dateList`.

```
global dateList
dateList = []

def getDateList():
    return dateList

def addDate(message):
    thisList.append(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_script1)
    process1.start()

    while(True):
        if (SIGNAL):
            # This print is allways 0
            print(len(getDateList()))
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

Any help on this is appreciated :)

I tried to move the location of the list around expecting the size to change inside the loop aswell as outside of it.

Comment: Can you also post the code that is executed in process1? Your code does not modify dateList at all. Maybe there is a typo in `addDate()`?

Comment: What/where is *run_script1* ? Also, MRE please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Raphael
Yes, its a typo. It is suppose to be:
dateList.append(message). Althought it still does not work. 
I'll try to upload the part of the code adding the message aswell, although I confirmed that part works. The list grows.

Comment: @Wickz yes, I'm sure the other part works, but we need to be able to understand your program. Here we cannot see how `addDate` is called or used. Please add enough code for a working MRE as DarkKnight said.